# Compare two generic items which has boolean properties, if any of them true returns true as in result generic list

Tags: c#, compare

I'm trying to compare two items which is generic with same properties inside in it.
If the property going to compare, in any one of the list item which is `true` means returns `TRUE` else as `FALSE` I'm new to c# so can't publish here the code sorry for inconvenience.
The item 1 and item 2 has same properties but calculated from different cases
: The Boolean properties needs to be checked.

```
public class RrmModulePermission : BaseEntity
    {

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int? DesignationId { get; set; }
        public int ModuleId { get; set; }
        public bool View { get; set; }
        public bool ViewAll { get; set; }
        public bool Add { get; set; }
        public bool Edit { get; set; }
        public bool Delete { get; set; }
        public bool Import { get; set; }
        public bool Export { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual RrmModule Modules { get; set; }

    }


 var list3 = new RrmModulePermission();
            if (list1.View || list2.View)
            {
                list3.View = true;
            }
            if (list1.Add || list2.Add)
            {
                list3.Add = true;
            }
            if (list1.Edit || list2.Edit)
            {
                list3.Edit = true;
            }
            if(list1.Delete || list2.Delete)
            {
                list3.Delete = true;
            }
            return list3;
```

Comment: Just compare every element from list 1 with every element from list 2. What exactly is your problem? What have you tried? Apart from this "I can´t publish code because I´m new to C#"? I can´t see what those two facts have to do with each other. Please share what you´ve tried and where exactly you have difficulties.

Comment: Can I repeat the question to make sure we're clear? You have two lists - different types - i.e. `List<Foo> `and `List<Bar>`; `Foo` and `Bar` have properties some of which intersect (namewise); you want to iterate through the two lists at the same time (presumably they have the same count), and check all of the `bool` properties that intersect, and if *either* object has a `true`... return `true` , else `false`... question: is that final result per pair? or overall? Also: are the types known at runtime? i.e. could you write this in regular C#? or are you looking for a reflection approach?

Comment: So you have two `List<RrmModulePermission>` and you want to find the differences regarding the `bool` properties?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes,I'm comparing the lists which has exactly same properties.Say If List<foo> has View = true, and List<bar> has View = false means In the result list View = true ...Like this for other properties as well For boolean cases alone! Now I hope you understood.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes.If any bool property corresponding comparison true means return as TRUE

Comment: OR `||` is the operator you're looking for. `true || true` = true, `true || false` = true, `false || false` = false

Comment: `if (SomeObject.View || OtherObject.View) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @Cid Exactly! How to do the same with two generic items?

Comment: But how did you know which data compare which data? because they are collection.

Comment: I have updated my code pls check now!

Comment: `list3.View = list1.View || list2.View;` will assign `true` or `false` depending of the result of the condition (and save a lots of lines). In your example, `list3.View` isn't set to false.

Comment: By the way, by list, you mean `List<RrmModulePermission>` or the list of the properties of an object of class `RrmModulePermission` ?

Comment: list of the properties of an object of class RrmModulePermission

Comment: So it looks like you made a very bad usage of the word list :) It's a keyword in programming, better use of object or item

Comment: I have remove it now! but sometime shows null value comparison exception.How to handle it please?

Comment: `bool` is struct and value type that will not be null

Comment: I know.But List1 and list2 variables may contains null obects.while checks it shows list1.view is null ...How to achieve this? @D-Shih

Comment: Which property did you considerate if that is `null` you expect false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you presented your code I would suggest initializing `list3` like so

```
// if both are null, return an object with all bools as false
if (list1 == null && list2 == null)
    return new RrmModulePermission();

// if list1 is null, set all bools to false
if (list1 == null)
    list1 = new RrmModulePermission();

// if list2 is null, set all bools to false
if (list2 == null)
    list2 = new RrmModulePermission();

var list3 = new RrmModulePermission
{
    View = list1.View || list2.View,
    ViewAll = list1.ViewAll || list2.ViewAll,
    Add = list1.Add || list2.Add,
    Edit = list1.Edit || list2.Edit,
    Delete = list1.Delete || list2.Delete,
    Import = list1.Import || list2.Import,
    Export = list1.Export || list2.Export
};

return list3;
```

*Note that if you set the default value of any of the properties to* `true` *you need to replace*

```
new RrmModulePermission();
```

*with (you only need to change the properties with the default value of* `true`*)*

```
new RrmModulePermission
{
    View = false,
    ViewAll = false,
    Add = false,
    Edit = false,
    Delete = false,
    Import = false,
    Export = false
};
```

*for example if only* `Add` *defaults to* `true` *use*

```
new RrmModulePermission { Add = false };
```

Comment: How do I compare if any one of them say list1.view or list2.view or both null ? if both null needs to returns as false...?

Comment: Do you mean `null` or `false` ? In C# a `bool` cannot be `null` (only a `bool?` can). the `||` operator is the logical *OR* operator. It returns `true` if at least one of the values is `true`. If both are `false` it returns `false`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I mean List1 and list2 is generic may contains null as like list1 = null so ,list1.view also null. So How to compare this case?

Comment: If `list1` is `null`, `list1.view` **is not** `null`, it doesn't exist. If you try to access `null.view` it will throw the infamous `NullReferenceException`. However I will edit my answer accordingly